# Bat file programme

Tags: batch-file

Bat file code for uninstall application with registry traces.

I tried below code:

```
Wmic product where "name = 'application name '" call uninstall /nointeractive.
```

Error returned:

> Uninstall - invalid alias verb.

Comment: Try without `/nointeractive` at the end. wmic has no `noninteractive` global switch

Comment: Still facing same error.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no `/nointeractive` option.

As long as you have the actual `application name`, *(I don't know if the trailing space in your `'application name '` string is an issue, make sure it is correct)*,  and it exists under `Win32_Product`, *(i.e. MSI installed products)*, this would be my suggestion:

```dos
Echo Y|WMIC Product Where "Name='application name'" Call Uninstall
```

Comment: What is the output of the following command: `WMIC Product Where "Name='application name'" Get Name`? _Please put the real application name in there!_